# How to Parse URL into Android

Tags: android, parsing

I have code in which I have to parse URL. If i am directly passing URL then parsing is done but if I am trying to make My URL dynamically to accept data then its showing Null Pointer Exception.. Plzz Help Me..

My URL's format is like this..

```
String loginUrl = "http://54.152.108.131/iphone111/getParentInput?child_id="+id+"&date="+date.toString();
```

if I put URL like this

```
http://54.152.108.131/iphone111/getParentInput?child_id=6272&date=1/19/2016
```

then its working.Please let me know where I am doing mistake..

My LogCat is here

```
01-19 08:09:43.628: E/AndroidRuntime(18018): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
01-19 08:09:43.628: E/AndroidRuntime(18018): Process: com.MyKidzDay, PID: 18018
01-19 08:09:43.628: E/AndroidRuntime(18018): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
01-19 08:09:43.628: E/AndroidRuntime(18018):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
01-19 08:09:43.628: E/AndroidRuntime(18018):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
01-19 08:09:43.628: E/AndroidRuntime(18018):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
01-19 08:09:43.628: E/AndroidRuntime(18018):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
01-19 08:09:43.628: E/AndroidRuntime(18018):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
01-19 08:09:43.628: E/AndroidRuntime(18018):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
01-19 08:09:43.628: E/AndroidRuntime(18018):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
01-19 08:09:43.628: E/AndroidRuntime(18018):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
01-19 08:09:43.628: E/AndroidRuntime(18018): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-19 08:09:43.628: E/AndroidRuntime(18018):    at com.KidsTabs.KidSummary$ParentInputData.doInBackground(KidSummary.java:1651)
01-19 08:09:43.628: E/AndroidRuntime(18018):    at com.KidsTabs.KidSummary$ParentInputData.doInBackground(KidSummary.java:1)
01-19 08:09:43.628: E/AndroidRuntime(18018):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
01-19 08:09:43.628: E/AndroidRuntime(18018):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
01-19 08:09:43.628: E/AndroidRuntime(18018):    ... 4 more
01-19 08:09:43.644: W/EGL_genymotion(18018): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-19 08:09:44.084: I/Inside convertstream method(18018): hello
```

Comment: Always post the logcat error trace when you talk about **Crash**, `NullPointerException`, **unfortunately app has stopped** etc. That is the key to the solution.

Comment: have you confirmed that both `id` and `date` have their values set before calling the code? Does the output of `date.toString()` match the format you are expecting?

Comment: yes I did,, I am able to see my Id and date value in LogCat

Comment: I recommend you use `StringBuilder` instead just String

Comment: Hi.. I have update my LogCat..

Comment: @zIronManBox.. I already tried URLEncoder but still I am getting Exception

Comment: The image doesn't contain full error. Please copy and paste it in the question.

Comment: hi @Rohit5k2 , I have updated my Questions with LogCat.. please let me know

Comment: Error is at line number **1651** in `KidSummary.java`. Please post the relevant code.

Comment: hi@Rohit5k2  this line indicate the Link which I had already posted in my question

String loginUrl = "http://54.152.108.131/iphone111/getParentInput?child_id="+id+"&date="+date.toString();

Comment: @kitkat ... try to display the value of loginUrl using Toast ... 
example : Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "value of loginUrl : " + loginUrl, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: Hello @Ivan I debugged my URL its showing correct URL

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have a null KidSummary object. Try to print the content at line 1351. It's important do post KidSummary class code and the ASyncTask implementation.